# Swift Firebase Storage - when updating data, image disappear from app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I've got a problem with updating data. As you can see on this picture below, when I change those three textfields but leave current image and tap "Save", it will update my data in Firebase but also will upload a NEW image which is EMPTY so user will see an empty UIImageView.

Why is that?

[Change Medication view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr4yK.png)

[Change Medication view no image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiULj.png)

This is my method from Firebase to save image(data) and download URL:

```
func saveImageToStorage(cellImage: Data, completion: @escaping(Result<String, Error>) -> Void) {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    refStorage.child(uid).child(imageName).putData(cellImage, metadata: nil) { (_, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            completion(.failure(NSError(domain: "Saving image to storage failed", code: 0)))
            return
        }
        
        self.refStorage.child(uid).child(self.imageName).downloadURL { (url, error) in
            guard let url = url, error == nil else { return }
            let urlString = url.absoluteString
            completion(.success(urlString))
            print("URL downloaded: \(urlString)")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is extension with UIImagePickerControllerDelegate:

```
extension CurrentMedicationSettingsViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    let compressionQualityValue: CGFloat = 0.1
    
    let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
    userMedicationSettingView.medicationImageView.image = image
    
    if let uploadData = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: compressionQualityValue) {
        imageData = uploadData
    }
    
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

ViewModel where update medication method is:

```
  func updateMedicationInfo(data: Data, pillName: String, capacity: String, dose: String, childId: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    firebaseManager.saveImageToStorage(cellImage: data) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        case .success(let url):
            self.firebaseManager.updateMedicationInfo(pillName: pillName, capacity: capacity, dose: dose, cellImageURL: url, childId: childId)
        }
        completion()
    }
}
```

Thanks for any advice!

Cheers!